# What is the best way to order a list by numeric field and put objects with value of 0 at the bottom?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a collection of objects.  Each object has a ranking field which is in an int.

I want to sort by ranking but put the items that have no ranking (rank field would be 0 ) at the bottom.

so here is the code that puts the 0's at the top:

```
 var sorted = myObjects.OrderBy(r=>r.Ranking);
```

I could create some new property called "RankForSorting" where if changes the value from 0 to 100000 so it sorts properly but i thought it would be more elegant and better to solve this in the OrderBy logic (rather than changing values).

The end result should look something like this

Rank:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 0
- 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First sort objects by ranking equal to zero. That will move objects without ranking to the bottom (because comparing ranking with zero gives you `true` for zero rankings and `false` for other rankings, and `true` is bigger than `false`). Than add sorting by ranking to sort both 'groups':

```
myObjects.OrderBy(r => r.Ranking == 0).ThenBy(r => r.Ranking);
```

Comment: wouldn't that put 0 items at the top?

Comment: @leora no, zero items will give `true` for first ordering, which is bigger than `false`. Thus you have ascending ordering, `true` will go to the bottom